# Mixed-Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image

Tags: android, reactjs, chromecast, content-security-policy, mixed-content

I'm facing an issue with my `ReactJS` code since I added the `react-native-google-cast` library in my project. 
The issue is the following : 
I want to cast to my Android TV a HTTP video source coming from the web. I added the `CastButton` in my application, which works fine and detects devices around me. 
But the problem is that, when I want to launch the cast to my Android TV box (**under Android 9**), it fails with the following message : `"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/default_receiver/1.0/app.html?skin=https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/0000/skins/cast/skin.css&google_cast_bg=true' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure video 'XXXX'. This content should also be served over HTTPS."`. 
After many researches over the Web I found that using the solution of this topic should do the trick, but it does not the error keeps coming. ([Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)).
I've found that the file `android/app/build/intermediates/instant_app_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:4` contains `android:targetSandboxVersion="2"`, but I can't override it as it's reload from somewhere (?) every rebuild. 
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.iptvapp"
  android:targetSandboxVersion="1"
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
        android:value="com.reactnative.googlecast.GoogleCastOptionsProvider" />
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cast HTTP video, you need to load cast_receiver_framework via HTTP to avoid mixed content. Google's cast receiver uses schemeless URLs like:

```
<script src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/caf_receiver/v3/cast_receiver_framework.js"></script>
```

**// [www.gstatic.com](http://www.gstatic.com)** means it will be loaded via current page loading scheme. Your app should be loaded via HTTP, then all libs will work via HTTP too.

Alternatively you can use an [upgrade-insecure-requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests) CSP directive and place:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

into `<head>` section. In this case browsers "magilally" replace all HTTP requests to HTTPS one. This variant is much secure then HTTP, but played videos should be accessible via HTTPS.